# HTTP Request Methods and AJAX. What is going on?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

So I'm working on a function that makes it easier to send XMLHttpRequest's.^

It's set up like this..

```
XHR(url, method, data);
```

..where data is an object that get's turned into a query string like..

```
XHR('Hey.xml', 'get', { hi: 'hey' });
```

..would request "Hey.xml?hi=hey".

The thing is, different request methods want the query to be sent in different ways.

GET and HEAD expect the query to be part of the url.

POST expects the query to be sent with..

```
request.send(query);
```

I know there are other methods, and I was wondering which way the other methods use, or if other methods use yet another way.

^ Yes I know 50 of these already exist. Yes I know jQuery is one of them. Don't even think about suggesting it.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: @Yuliy I've looked through that, but it doesn't talk about how the differences work with XHR. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading on AJAXPatterns.org, there isn't any differences when using the "other" request methods with XHR.

Take a look at http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call#Handling_POSTs_and_Other_Request_Types

Answer (score 1):

No, there are more. You got at least PUT and DELETE, although they are used much less frequent  than GET and POST (as in: hardly ever). I believe GET is the only one that works cross domain. The others only work in your own domain, so it is your own decision whether to use POST, PUT or DELETE.

Comment: Do any methods besides GET and POST return the file body?

Comment: To my knowledge, they shouldn't. But it is possible. There's not much difference in how the methods actually work. A small difference is that posted data is sent in the headers instead of in the url. Apart from that, all methods are more or less the same and should be able to behave in the same way. These different commands are merely semantics, and they are rarely used. In many cases GET or POST are used to delete resources as well, just as POST is used insted of PUT to upload files.

Comment: @GolexTrol So I take it POST is the only method that expects the data to be a header?